# How to import clips from one project into another in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere

I have imported one project into another in Premier. After that I got all clips I had in old project visible in new one, at left. But I need only some of them. Unfortunately, when I am trying to delete clips, I get a message:

[image]

which makes me think, that if I agree, I will delete clip from both project.

But I don't want to touch old project. How to import clips leaving old project intact?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one of the clips you used in the old project, you should only import that one and don't even use the old project file. Locate the clip on your hard drive and import it into premiere, e.g. by dragging it onto the project panel. If you have trouble finding it, open the old project, find the clip in the project panel and right-click -> **Reveal in Explorer...**. That should show you it's location on your hard drive.